# How to Copy SmsTSLog file to USB

Tags: copy, sccm

I'm trying to **deploy** an **operating system** to a target machine **via SCCM**.

Unfortunately, there are **errors** in the **deployment process** and as a consequence, the target machine has not received the operating system correctly.

In order to *ascertain what* **errors** are occurring in the deployment process, I wish to **view log file(s)** for errors. These errors are invariably **located** in the **SMSTSLog** file on the target machine.

In given the fact that the target machine is **not booting**,  how can one **copy** the SMSTSLog  from the target machine onto an external USB key in order to view that log file for various errors on another computer?

Answer (score 0):

- Plug in into the target machine the **USB key** which contains the
  *task sequence* for deployment .
- Press F12 (Dell machines) to *load* the **boot options**.

**If** it's a *legacy boot* then choose the *USB Storage* which contains the task sequence.

**or**

**If** its a *UEFI boot* then choose *UEFI option*.

For help in identifying which boot option, look at the *memory size* of the mounted external memory on the boot list.

If the size listed is similar to the size of your USB stick  (e.g. UEFI: Jetflash 2GB)  then this is your target USB stick to boot from.

Wait for the files to load from the USB.

- When the **task sequence launches** from the USB stick **press F8**
  to bring up a **command prompt**. Note: Pressing F8 multiple times launches multiple command prompts.
- A *Task Sequence Wizard* window may appear. Simply move this window to
  the side of the screen as you are only interested in bringing up a
  command prompt.

It is necessary to **identify** the **label volume** for the **external USB** key.

To do this do the following inside the command prompt:

1. type: **Diskpart**
2. Then type: **List Volume**

You will see a number of volumes listed.

- *Look* for the *volume* of type **removable** (as you should only have one removable USB connected to the machine at this time) and
  **note its label** e.g. D
- Press F8 again to bring up another command prompt window.
- You will now attempt to **copy** the log file with the following command:

  **xcopy** *[source] [destination]*
- E.g. Type: **xcopy** X:\windows\temp\SMSTSLog*.* D:\

**Source** is: X:\windows\temp\SMSTSLog*.*

**Destination** is: D:\

Then simply remove the USB stick and open in another machine to view SMSTSLog with your editor of choice.

Comment: For this to work you have to activate "Enable command support (testing only)" in the properties of your boot image. It's super useful though so if you do not have security concerns about it, it might be nice to always have it on